# Как отсортировать таблицу в php

Tags: php, сортировка

В общем при добавлении новой строки она добавляется вверх а мне нужно что б ниже той которая уже существует, сам скрипт ниже заранее спасибо)
    <?php 
    include ("bd.php");

```
if ( !isset( $_GET["action"] ) ) $_GET["action"] = "showlist";

switch ( $_GET["action"] )
{
  case "showlist":   
    show_list(); break;
  case "addform":     
    get_add_item_form(); break;
  case "add":        
    add_item(); break;
  case "editform":  
    get_edit_item_form(); break;
  case "update":      
    update_item(); break;
  case "delete":     
    delete_item(); break;
  default:
    show_list();
}

function show_list()
{
  $query = 'SELECT id, icon, data, name, glob, room, skype, mail, game FROM users';
  $res = mysql_query( $query );
  echo '<h2>Список</h2>';
  echo '<div class="span8">';
  echo '<table  class=" table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">';
  echo '<thead>';
  echo 
  '<tr>
  <th>Иконка</th>
  <th>Дата создания</th>
  <th>Ник на сервере</th>
  <th>Уникальный ID</th>
  <th>Название комнаты</th>
  <th>Skype</th>
  <th>Mail</th>
  <th>4Game</th>
  <th>Ред.</th>
  <th>Удл.</th>
  </tr>';
  while ( $item = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) )
  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['icon'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['data'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['glob'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$item['room'].'</td>';
    if ($item["skype"]!=Null) {
    echo  '<td>'.'<center>'.'<a href="skype:'.$item["skype"].'?call">'.'<img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/smallicon/'.$item["skype"].'" style="border: none;" width="16" height="16" />'.'</a>'.'</center>'.'</td>';
    } else {
    echo '<td><center>нет</center></td>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.$item['mail'].'</td>';
    if ($item["game"]!=Null) {
    echo  '<td><center><a href="https://forum.4game.ru/member.php?u='.$item["game"].'" target="_blank"><img src="/img/a3c49ce5948a.png" /></a></center></td>';
    } else {
    echo '<td><center>нет</center></td>';
    }
    echo '<td><center><a class="btn btn-warning" href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=editform&id='.$item['id'].'" ><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></center></td>';

    echo '<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=delete&id='.$item['id'].'"><center><button class="btn btn-danger" ><i class="icon-trash"></i></button></center></a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  } 
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<p><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=addform" class="btn">Добавить</a></p>';  
  }

function get_add_item_form()
{
  echo '<div class="span5">';
  echo '<h2>Добавить</h2>'; 
  echo '<div class="modal-body">';
  echo '<form class="table" name="addform" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=add" method="POST">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="icon" placeholder="иконка клана" value="" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Дата создания" value="" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ник на сервере" value="" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="glob" placeholder="Уникальный ID" type="text" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="room" placeholder="Название комнаты" type="text" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="skype" placeholder="Skype" type="text" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Почта" type="text" />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="game" placeholder="Профиль на 4Game" type="text" />';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '<div class="modal-footer">';
  echo '<button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Отменить</button></a>';
  echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохранить">';
  echo '</form>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}

function add_item()
{
  $icon = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['icon'] );
  $data = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['data'] );
  $name = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['name'] );
  $glob = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['glob'] );
  $room = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['room'] );
  $skype = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['skype'] );
  $mail = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['mail'] );
  $game = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['game'] );
  $query = "INSERT INTO users (icon, data, name, glob, room, skype, mail, game ) VALUES ('".$icon."', '".$data."', '".$name."', '".$glob."', '".$room."', '".$skype."', '".$mail."', '".$game."' );";
  mysql_query ( $query );
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
}

function get_edit_item_form()
{
  $query = 'SELECT icon, data, name, glob, room, skype, mail, game FROM users WHERE id='.$_GET['id'] ;
  $res = mysql_query( $query );
  $item = mysql_fetch_array( $res );
  echo '<div class="span5">';
  echo '<h2>Редактировать</h2>'; 
  echo '<center>';
  echo '<div class="modal-body">';
  echo '<form name="editform" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?action=update&id='.$_GET['id'].'" method="POST">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="icon" placeholder="иконка клана" value="'.$item['icon'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Дата создания" value="'.$item['data'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ник на сервере" value="'.$item['name'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="glob" placeholder="Уникальный ID" value="'.$item['glob'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="room" placeholder="Название комнаты" value="'.$item['room'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="skype" placeholder="Skype" value="'.$item['skype'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Почта"  value="'.$item['mail'].'">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="game" placeholder="Профиль на 4Game" value="'.$item['game'].'">';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</center>';
  echo '<div class="modal-footer">';
  echo '<button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Отменить</button></a>';
  echo '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохранить">';
  echo '</form>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}

function update_item()
{
  $icon = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['icon'] );
  $data = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['data'] );
  $name = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['name'] );
  $glob = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['glob'] );
  $room = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['room'] );
  $skype = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['skype'] );
  $mail = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['mail'] );
  $game = mysql_escape_string( $_POST['game'] );
  $query = "UPDATE users SET icon='".$icon."', data='".$data."', name='".$name."', glob='".$glob."', room='".$room."', skype='".$skype."', mail='".$mail."', game='".$game."'
            WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
  mysql_query ( $query );
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
}

function delete_item()
{
  $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
  mysql_query ( $query );
  header( 'Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
  die();
}

?>
```

Comment: о, мои глаза...

Comment: неужели всё так ужасно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В функции `function show_list()`
запрос поменяй на вот етот

```
$query = 'SELECT id, icon, data, name, glob, room, skype, mail, game FROM users ORDER BY id ASC';
```

и еще замечания - в функциях update_item() и delete_item() ты в запрос суешь переменную от юзера без проверок $_GET['id'] - это не есть хорошо

И еще одно замечание - перед выводом из БД используй функцию htmlspecialchars() для полей чтоб превратить спецсимволы HTML в сущьности, так если ввсести в твою таблицу теги html - то у тебя они тоже отработают как теги а не символы.

Comment: спасиб помогло)))
а какого типа проверка надо?

Comment: ну сделай так $id=(int)$_GET['id'];  и далее везде используй $id всместо  $_GET['id']

Comment: это исправил)))
сейчас буду править спецсимволы 
спасиб за замечания)))